# multiple records in sharepoint workflow

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-workflow

I would like like to send an email to user when my criteria meets, but I can only get the workflow designer to return one record.

I have two lists and I have data something like below.

List A:

```
**col1**                **col2**
abc@a23.com             This is subject
```

List B:

```
Col1            Key1                  Key2             
abc@123.com     orange               apple
abc@123.com     banana               subject
```

Iam writing the condition

if col1(A) equals col1(B)

and col1(A) contains key1 or key2

do something.

But it looks like only first row is getting selected all the time and nothing is happening as it not matching with keyword column. IS there a way to implement this in sharepoint designer as there is a limitation that only first row will be selected if multiple rows returned. Plz help me. Let me know if I am unclear.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this in SharePoint Designer, they way I've duct taped this together in the past was to create another list that is a one for your many... based upon your list a and list b

Create a new list as such.

List C
Col 1              Key1        Key2     Key1-1      Key2-1    Key1-2     Key2-2
 
abc@a23.com        Lookup to List B   Lookup to List B    Lookup to List B    http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

With  the new list created you update it based upon Column1 1 (you'll have to manually update Key1 with the values from the lookups.  From there your workflow can successfully query and email based upon list C (I'd probably put the workflow on list C and have it trigger when the appropariate number of items have been added.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Can you please explain me with example.I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a task that is running into this problem as well. Email all contacts where the record has a particular flag.

Example List:

```
Record | Group A | Group B | Group C | Contacts
-----------------------------------------------
1       [Checked]           [Checked]  Names
2                 [Checked] [Checked]  Names
3       [Checked]                      Names
```

While I have not succeeded in getting this to work. I did move one step closer today. Namely, I have two Workflow Variables - Collector and Bucket.

I am using the following:

```
Set Variable:Bucket to [%Variable: Bucket%][%Variable: Collector%]
```

The above line has allowed me to append emails to a single variable.  Now if we can combine this with a way to check "each" record.  Then we will have a solution.